# Autohotkey two buttons pressed result in third button

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, shortcut, key-bindings

im new to autohotkey. What i want to do:

```
A press = A press
D press = D press
A press + D press = C press AND A press 
D press + A press = E press AND D press 
A hold + D hold = A hold AND C press
D hold + A hold = D hold AND E press
```

For example A and D held down should result such text in notepad:

```
adcaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

D and A held down to result:

```
daedddddddddddddd
```

A and D pressed to result:

```
adc
```

All i want to do is to keep A and D keys functionality untouched, but when held together - triggering C or E keys depending on pressing order. Ty in advance!

I've tried this but it returns error:

```
~a & d::c & d
~d & a::e & a
```

Only works like that, but it doesnt return a or d when held down

```
~a & d::c
~d & a::e
```

Comment: `a & d:: Send c` and `a:: Send a`  See [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Comment: not the solution, unfortunately. Its actually the same as "semi-working" ~a & d::c , which i jst hinted above. The issue is the same. A and D held down doesnt result in both A and C key being printed, it just returns C